# How to make SQL Server to save datetime with AM/PM format?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, datetime

I'm trying to make my SQL Server table `datetime` columns save `datetime` with AM/PM. How to make SQL Server to save `datetime` with AM/PM format?

Right now it saves date like this: `2012-01-23 14:47:00.000`
Is it possible to save it `2012-01-23 02:47:00.000 PM` ??

Or does SQL Server save the date and time in this format (`2012-01-23 14:47:00.000`) all the time and I need to convert it just on output and input?

Is it even possible to save it in this format (`2012-01-23 02:47:00.000 PM`)? Or does SQL Server save `datetime` in 24 hour format?

thanks indeed for any help. sorry for language. ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Internally the date and time are stored as a number.

Whether it's displayed in a 12 or 24 hour clock is up to the program formatting it for display.

Comment: so you mean what in database the datetime field gonna look like this(2012-01-23 14:47:00.000) all the time. and its completely up to program settings how it will be displayed for end user?

Comment: @Mindaugas No, it will look like 35565.34536426, and other tools interpret this number as date and time

Comment: for more on how insert to **using sql query** check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12957635/2218697)

Answer (score 5):

As Andrew said, Datetime format is stored not as string. so, you can use `CONVERT` function to get the datetime value in approprate format. for example,

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), GETDATE(), 100)
```

to learn more about datetime formatting, see [this article](http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/date-formats.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

AM/PM serves only for visualization, if you need to display them, use CONVERT keyword:

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar, YourDateTimeField, 109)
FROM YourTable
```

If you need to store AM/PM - it is makes no sense for `datetime` type, use `varchar` type instead.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply use CONVERT function as following:

select CONVERT(VARCHAR,GETDATE(),108)

http://www.fmsinc.com/free/NewTips/SQL/AM_PM_time_format_in_SQL.asp

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Aa226054

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kathykam/archive/2006/09/29/773041.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the accuracy of the datetime you are storing you might be able to clean it up with

REPLACE(CONVERT (varchar, YourDateTimeField, 109), ':00.0000000', ' ')

This will not work if your date field is populated with GETDATE() as that means it will contain seconds and milliseconds but it will work if the field is populated by a user and seconds and milliseconds are all zeros