# Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

Tags: sql-server-2008, datetime, varchar

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2, and I've selected the option to export the data from a table into a SQL INSERT script using 'Script data as' -> 'INSERT with column names'. This has resulted in a script similar to the following:

```
INSERT INTO [MyTable] ([Id],[InsertDateTime],[Firstname],[Email]) VALUES (1, '26/06/2012 2:02:25 p.m.', 'Robert', 'robert@test.com');
INSERT INTO [MyTable] ([Id],[InsertDateTime],[Firstname],[Email]) VALUES (2, '28/06/2012 4:17:21 a.m.', 'David', 'david@test.com');
```

If I then immediately try to run this generated script on an empty version of the table, I get the following error:

```
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
```

2 Questions:

1. The date/time string is in the format 'dd/mm/yyyy h:mm:ss'. How do I tell SQL server the specific format that I want to convert the string representation of the date/time from? The script generates about 5000 INSERT lines, so I can do a find and replace where it's reasonable to do so...
2. Why would SQL Server even generate a script that it cannot run?

Thanks!

Comment: this post might give your answers. 
[how-to-make-sql-server-to-save-datetime-with-am-pm-format][1]

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8983314/how-to-make-sql-server-to-save-datetime-with-am-pm-format

Comment: sorry for formatting error. link is not getting formatted due to some reason.

Answer (score 0):

First use [set dateformat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa259188%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) to set proper date parts order. In your case "dmy". Then replace all "a.m." to "AM" and "p.m" to "PM" in all your statements. Following script works fine:

```
 set dateformat dmy

 INSERT INTO [MyTable] ([Id],[InsertDateTime],[Firstname],[Email]) 
   VALUES (1, '26/06/2012 2:02:25 PM', 'Robert', 'robert@test.com');
 INSERT INTO [MyTable] ([Id],[InsertDateTime],[Firstname],[Email]) 
     VALUES (2, '28/06/2012 4:17:21 AM', 'David', 'david@test.com');
```

Comment: If "a.m." and "p.m." are not recognised by SQL Server, why would one of SSMS's own built in scripts generate a date format that cannot be recognised?